# BATCH FOR LOOP TO RECONIZE NON-DATA Between Delims

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

**LINES_W_APT.txt:**

```
format- callsign:cid:realname:clienttype:frequency:latitude:longitude:altitude:groundspeed:planned_aircraft:planned_tascruise:planned_depairport:planned_altitude:planned_destairport:server:protrevision:rating:transponder:facilitytype:visualrange:planned_revision:planned_flighttype:planned_deptime:planned_actdeptime:planned_hrsenroute:planned_minenroute:planned_hrsfuel:planned_minfuel:planned_altairport:planned_remarks:planned_route:planned_depairport_lat:planned_depairport_lon:planned_destairport_lat:planned_destairport_lon:atis_message:time_last_atis_received:time_logon:heading:QNH_iHg:QNH_Mb:

N12345:1453923:John Doe:PILOT::40.68993:-115.43299:16000:269:PC12/G:0:KBAM:16000:KENV:USA-EAST:100:1:6015:0:0:1:I:415:0:0:59:4:0::  /v/:BAM V32 SPATS:0:0:0:0::20200928040856:20200928040856:79:29.92:1013:

SWA1774A:1434567:Jane Doe:ATC:199.998:45.58966:-122.59018:0:0::::::USA-WEST:100:1:0:0:40::::::::::::0:0:0:0::20200927044935:20200927044935:0:0:0:
```

---

**BATCH CODE:**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo.
echo.
ECHO FLID              TYP               ALT               BCN               RTE
ECHO _________________________________________________________________________________________________
ECHO.
    for /f "tokens=1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,17,21,28,29,30 delims=:" %%a in (LINES_W_APT.txt) do (
        set "FLID=%%a                  "
        set "LAT=%%b                  "
        set "LONG=%%c                  "
        set "CUR_ALT=%%d                  "
        set "GS=%%e                  "
        set "TYP=%%f                  "
        set "TAS=%%g                  "
        set "DEP=%%h"
        set "REQ_ALT=%%i                  "
        set "ARR=%%j"
        set "BCN=%%k                  "
        set "FLT_RULES=%%l                  "
        set "ALT_APT=%%m                  "
        set "RMK=%%n                  "
        set "RTE=%%o                  "
        set "CUSTOM_RTE=(%%l) %%h ./. %%j  (%%m)"
        if /i NOT %%d==0 echo !FLID:~0,18!!TYP:~0,18!!REQ_ALT:~0,18!!BCN:~0,18!!CUSTOM_RTE:~0,25!
    )
endlocal
```

---

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
FLID              TYP               ALT               BCN               RTE
_________________________________________________________________________________________________

N12345            PC12/G            16000             6015              (I) KBAM ./. KENV  (  /v/
```

---

**ISSUE:**

When there is no data between delims, my FOR loop seems to go on to the next instance that has a value.

For example: The return I get for "planned_altairport" on N12345 is actually the "planned_remarks".

---

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:**

I could only think of one solution and that was to run a script that replaced every double colon mark in LINES_W_APT.txt with data like so:

```
powershell -Command "(gc LINES_W_APT.txt) -replace '::', ':NONE:' | Out-File -encoding ASCII LINES_W_APT.txt"
```

But that only results in something like this happening with strings that have multiple double colons in a row for entries such as SWA1774A:

```
:NONE::NONE::NONE::NONE
```

So... I am still left with some double colons and messes up the entire format and data now.

Any ideas on how to get my for loop to recognize a NON-DATA between delims?

Comment: Please do not add solutions to your question area, I have removed your latest edit. If you'd like to help future readers, post your solution an answer in the answer area provided. You could, if you feel it is the preferred solution to your question, and within the remit of the provided information and tags, mark your own answer as accepted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q64096160.txt"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%A IN (%filename1%) DO (
 set "oline=%%A"&set "oline=!oline:::=: :!"&set oline=!oline:::=: :!"
 echo !oline!
)
```

Here's a batch-only version... The preliminary code just makes it easier for me to test on my system. The result is in `oline` ready to be parsed by `for /f "tokens=1,....,30 delims=:" %%a in ("!oline!") do (